# Count within intervals in O(log(n)) time

Tags: java, intervals, asymptotic-complexity

I have 2 arrays of intervals, trip_beginning and trip_end. 
trip_beginning[j] trip_end[j] representing the end and beginning of the jth interval.
Arrays M and S are sorted.

The program needs to filter out trips (badTrip) if it contains any index in S, and if it is not a badTrip, it needs to count up the number of M indexes in its interval.
The trip with the maxCt count (tripMax) at the end wins.

The code returns the correct result but needs to be asymptotically quicker.
T*(log(M+S).
Because of the for loop this is not the case.
Is there are quicker way to do the inter-interval (incl. endpoint) comparisons?

```
int tripMax = 0;
int maxCt = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

for (int j=0; j< trip_beginning.length; j++){
    int tripNo = j+1;
    boolean badTrip = false;
    int tripS = trip_beginning[j];
    int tripE = trip_end[j];
    int mountains = 0;


        for (int k=tripS; k <= tripE; k++){
            if (Bsearch(S,k)==1){
                badTrip= true;
                // break;
            } 
            if (!badTrip && Bsearch(M,k)==1){
                    mountains++;
            }

        } //endfor


    if (!badTrip && (mountains>maxCt)){
        maxCt = mountains;
        tripMax = tripNo;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only do binary search on two values: trip_beginning[j] and trip_end[j] + 1, instead of every integer between them. The binary search should find the maximum index which the corresponding value is smaller than the number to be searched for (-1 if smaller or equal to the first number in the array). Then calculate the index difference between the two ends of the trip. For S, if the index difference is not 0, then some elements in S are between the two ends, therefore a bad trip. For M, the index difference is the number of mountains. This gives O(n(log|S| + log|M|)) time.

Comment: Thanks - 
"The binary search should find the maximum index which the corresponding value is smaller than the number to be searched for."
so if not found and less than all values will return -1. If not found and greater than all values will return index at end of array?

Comment: @Mathflunkie Yes, exactly.